# Internet explorer 10 - TD height set to 0 - Not showing up TD contents

Tags: internet-explorer, html-table

IE10: I am trying to display a table on IE10, some of the cells data are missing. This work fine on IE9 and Chrome. When I refresh page, these cells shows the content but again contents from some other cells doesnt display.
When I used developer tool on IE, I can see style etc for these cells are exactly same compared to cells that are showing data with only one difference as below

In Developers Tool --> Layout tab, when I inspect these TDs, it shows height as 0px, but for other normal TDs it shows height as 10.19px, I am very sure that in src these TDs are exactly same (Style, height, width etc), seems that there is problem in rendering in IE10. When looked in HTML src, it shows content for TDs which are not getting rendered.

Src for TD:

```
<td width="" align="left" class="" id="Row16Col5" valign="middle" colspan="1">
```

Any idea whats wrong here?

I see similar question in Microsoft forum with status as Wont Fix!
http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/867361/ie10-premature-rendering-causes-blocks-to-not-show-content-e-g-td-or-div-gets-0px-height

Answer (score 0):

If possible please include a link to your website or mashup with your posts...

historically IE does not render superfluous td or br elements....
eg.

```html
<table style="border:solid 1px red; width:500px">
  <tr><td> </td></tr>
</table>
<!-- empty cells (including whitespace) are not displayed -->

<table style="border:solid 1px red; width:500px">
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<!-- fix the issue by adding &nbsp; to the cell contents -->
```

Note: try to avoid using depreciated presentational elements (height, width, align, valign)...
use css rules instead...

colspan and rowspan attributes for table cells are still used, but they must add up to the total number of cells specified in the first row of a table.... again validating your markup will show colspan errors.

validate your page markup at validator.w3.org - it will tell you if you are using depreciated presentational attributes (depends on your document type declaration).